# Can not get DataFrame to pivot

Tags: python, datatable, tableau-api

Im am getting data from a tablue worksheet and passing it into a Pandas Data Frame i the need to Pivot the data to be in the needed format how ever does not seem to be changing when run

```
C Week   Measure Names NT Login        Site Measure Values
```

0  202306       Calls AHT   1daa04  Derby Sell              0
1  202306       All Calls   1daa04  Derby Sell            972
2  202306      Core Calls   1daa04  Derby Sell            972
3  202306     Glass Calls   1daa04  Derby Sell              0
4  202306  Outbound Calls   1daa04  Derby Sell              9

Need to show as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFcHF.png)

View data df if the data frame the data is loaded in to, however after the below line is run the Dataframe looks exactly the same

```
view_data_df.pivot_table(values = 'Measure Values', 
                         index=['C Week','NT Login','Site'],
                         columns = 'Measure Names', 
                         aggfunc=sum).reset_index()
print(view_data_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas does not usually mutate inplace unless an inplace kwarg is offered.

I think you just need to reassign your dataframe to the pivoted version.

Additionally you should try to use chaining and vertical alignment when possible and practical.

Also to add a code block just use 3 tildas to start and end you code block.

```
pivot_table_df = (view_data_df
                  .pivot_table(values = 'Measure Values', 
                               index=['C Week','NT Login','Site'],
                               columns = 'Measure Names', 
                               aggfunc=sum)
                  .reset_index()
                  )
print(pivot_table_df)
```

This very clearly shows that we are starting with view_data_df, making a pivot table, resetting the index, and storing all of those changes in pivot_table_df. Hopefully, this is what you need.

Comment: Perfect thanks you very much i cant believe ive spent 2 to 3 hours on this and that was the result this worked exactly as needed